# Window Application in web site

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am Creating Application in Asp.NET . In That I have to run one windows application in the Page itself. How to Run the Windows Application in web form itself in asp.net c# ?

Answer (score 2):

you cant run window app inside web app unless you converted the window app to usercontrol. check the following example http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/asprabahar/1WindowsonWeb05302006023206AM/1WindowsonWeb.aspx

or you can rewrite the window application as wpf  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480223.aspx

Comment: Oh .OK .Is there any alternative solution for that?

Comment: imho, ActiveX is very bad approach, that will work mostly in IE and only on Windows. some other browser support it, but there is no good way to use them

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct way to run Windows applications in browser.

Most effective attempts to bring desktop computing power to the browser are Flash and Silverlight.

Silverlight, although being discontinued product, may fit you particular need. XPAB applications, are a special form of WPF apps that can be rather seemlessly ran from browser, but would benefit from a higher desktop intractability and performance.

Please read more by following [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970060%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can run windows app as process on web server, but they will be executed on web server side, and user won't see it. For UI application it has no sense.

All other approaches like ActiveX, Silverlight, etc are not so good as they are not supported widely.

ActiveX will work only in IE and only on Windows. Silverlight works, but not so good, and it will require additional plugin, and won't work on mobile phones.

The most normal way to do it is to **rewrite** your windows application as usual html web application. But if the application is huge, then it will require a lot of time to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your windows application into ActiveX which could run in Internet Explorer by enabling ActiveX in the security settings. Using ActiveX if your windows application is built by WinForms, and using Silverlight instead if your windows application is built by WPF/Silverlight.